# Web add-in loads in browser outlook bot not native desktop Outlook

Tags: office-addins

I have built a Word add-in that works in both native desktop Word and browser Word.  I have an Outlook add-in which works in browser Outlook but when I add it to native desktop Outlook I see this:

- add my addin through Get Add-ins > My Addins > Add from File
- I see the addin
- I close the dialog
- the addin does not appear in the ribbon
- I re-open the Get Addins dialog and my addin is not there.

Outlook version: Outlook for Office 365 MSO (16.0.12228.20322) 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else does something silly...

I followed the good old process of elimination, starting with a working manifest from [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-add-in-command-demo/blob/master/command-demo-manifest.xml).

One thing that confused me slightly is that Outlook Desktop often takes a while to show the add-in in the ribbon.

However the solution was that I had duplicated one of my Url elements.  When I removed the duplicate Url then the manifest worked in Outlook desktop.

If anyone from the Office addin team reads this it would be great if Outlook threw an exception when I had duplicate Url elements, rather than accepting the manifest.